# How can I type a "tiny" e?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

[image]

How can I type a "tiny" e in this picture? As many other math fonts, I don't know the name of this font so I cannot google it.

[image]

Its angle differs from a "regular" e.

Comment: Hello ! `$e$` is not working for you ?

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. For my humble opinion is an "e" in math-mode in Times-New Roman (the clone is `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`).

Comment: The picture shows Times for text and Computer Modern for math. Not an example to imitate.

Comment: @Sebastiano I've seen this "e" is used with a different meaning with a regular "e" before (maybe Euler's constant or electron? I don't remeber)

Comment: @ikh Please, can you put a complete and compilable example? This help us a lot for your question.

Comment: it is just a standard math italic e, as always if you have the pdf of that document you could check which fonts are being used, but the markup is simply `$aa^{-1}=e$`

Comment: There is also `$\dots {\scriptstyle e} \dots$`.